# Magento 2 : Coupon code couldn't be applied. Too many coupon code requests

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.2, coupon-codes

Magento 2: coupon code couldn't be applied. Too many coupon code requests, please try again later

Sales rule API :

Request: http://localhost/demonew/rest/V1/salesRules/1

Body:

```
> {   "rule": {
>     "rule_id": 1,
>     "name": "demo30",
>     "store_labels": [
>       {
>         "store_id": 0,
>         "store_label": "demo1",
>         "extension_attributes": {}
>       }
>     ],
>     "description": "",
>     "website_ids": [
>         1
>     ],
>     "customer_group_ids": [
>        0,
>        1,
>        2,
>        3
>     ],
>     "from_date": "2020-08-08",
>     "to_date": "2040-10-20",
>     "uses_per_customer": 0,
>     "is_active": true,
>     "condition": {
>       "condition_type": "",
>       "conditions": [
>         null
>       ],
>       "aggregator_type": "",
>       "operator": "",
>       "attribute_name": "",
>       "value": "",
>       "extension_attributes": {}
>     },
>     "action_condition": {
>       "condition_type": "",
>       "conditions": [
>         null
>       ],
>       "aggregator_type": "",
>       "operator": "",
>       "attribute_name": "",
>       "value": "",
>       "extension_attributes": {}
>     },
>     "stop_rules_processing": false,
>     "is_advanced": true,
>     "product_ids": [
>       0
>     ],
>     "sort_order": 0,
>     "simple_action": "by_percent",
>     "discount_amount": 15,
>     "discount_step": 0,
>     "apply_to_shipping": false,
>     "times_used": 0,
>     "is_rss": true,
>     "coupon_type": "SPECIFIC_COUPON",
>     "use_auto_generation": false,
>     "uses_per_coupon": 0,
>     "simple_free_shipping": "0"   } }
```

[image]